Error downloading 'pyannote/speaker-diarization' pipeline despite having read access token
I'm trying to use the pyannote.audio library to download the "pyannote/speaker-diarization" pipeline, but I keep encountering the following error:
Could not download 'pyannote/speaker-diarization' pipeline.
It might be because the pipeline is private or gated so make
sure to authenticate. Visit https://hf.co/settings/tokens to
create your access token and retry with:

   >>> Pipeline.from_pretrained('pyannote/speaker-diarization',
   ...                          use_auth_token='hf...')

I have a read-type access token, but the error persists. Here’s the code I’m using:
from pyannote.audio import Pipeline

pipeline = Pipeline.from_pretrained(
    'pyannote/speaker-diarization',
    use_auth_token='YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'
)

You can find the code I'm running in this Colab notebook as shown below:
enter image description here
Pyannote plays and Whisper rhymes v 2.1.
Any help would be appreciated!

We had a similar problem in a Huggingface space. Despite having set up a token called HF_TOKEN in the space's secrets, the code
pipeline = Pipeline.from_pretrained("pyannote/speaker-diarization-3.1",use_auth_token='HF_TOKEN')
would give the same error you are seeing.
Changing the code to
pipeline = Pipeline.from_pretrained("pyannote/speaker-diarization-3.1",use_auth_token=True)
fixed the issue.
